# Where can I ask this question about operating systems and software uninstallation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been trying to ask this question on various Stack Exchange sites, but it's not being received very well. Can someone point me to the correct place to ask this (maybe a Stack Exchange site is not the right place)?

I am trying to ask about complete software uninstallation. Coming from Windows, I want to find an OS that will allow me to easily completely uninstall a program/package and everything associated with it: all dependencies, all configuration files, all data files, and all traces in logs and $HOME (I heard changes could occur here). Basically, something where, after uninstallation, the system is the exact same as it was before uninstallation.

Comment: An alternative approach might be to ask how to do this in your OS of choice. There's a lot of container and sandbox options that are OS specific (more or less) that might work.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to find an OS...

In this case, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) may be your best bet. As the name suggests, they recommend software based on certain criteria. Make sure to read this [question asking guide](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/208) and clearly specify the criteria you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I have asked it there, but no one seems to be responding. Do you have any other suggestions as to where I could ask this question?

Comment: @user15088299 Just because no one's responding doesn't mean you went to the wrong place. Not everyone is constantly checking the site :) Wait a day or two, then everyone in different timezones will have a chance to see the question. It's also possible someone is researching an answer or otherwise working on your question

Comment: (I'll also add that smaller sites, like Software Recs, are usually slower to give feedback/answers than bigger sites, simply because there are less users)

Comment: @user15088299 - Your only alternative would be outside of the Stack Exchange community.  There isn't another community where a question, requesting a software recommendation, would be within scope.  It would also be inappropriate for you to ask the same question at multiple communities.